# Activity communication between custom flavor packages

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle, android-productflavors

I'd like to use a custom `Activity1` class for a specific gradle flavor, but when I try to launch that activity from an `MyActivity`  under `/main` it doesn't recognize `Activity1`  as a class. How can I build this communication, and where should I include `Activity1` in a manifest file, under `/flavor1` or under `/main`? My project structure:

```
|--src/
   |--flavor1/
    |--java/
      |  |--Activity1.java
   |  |--res/
   |     |--layout/
   |     |  |--activity1.xml   
   |--main/
      |--java/
      |  |--MyActivity.java
      |--res/
      |  |--layout/
      |  |  |--activity_main.xml
      |  |--...
      |--AndroidManifest.xml
```

I am adding in gradle:

```
sourceSets {
    flavor1.java.srcDirs 'src/flavor1/java'
}
```

And in `MyActivity` from `/main` I get:

> Cannot resolve symbol Activity1

P.S. As an alternative might be using of broadcast receivers byun I am not sure if that's a good approach

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the `flavor1` specific build variant is selected in the `Build Variants` window. (Bottom-left in Android Studio). Select any build variant which has the word `flavor1` in its name and you will see the classes in your `flavor1` sourceset. If another flavor varaint is selected only classes in that flavor's sourceset will be resolvable.

Comment: I am doing like this but my class is staying unresolvable

Comment: what does your error message look like? when you point on the unresolved class name

Comment: you do not need to specify the srcDirs when you already have the directory named same as the flavor name and proper folder structure. Remove the explicit assignment of srcDirs and then try.

Comment: @ AndroidMechanic deleted it, clean& rebuild and problem is the same

Comment: thats strange. btw - in your tree in the question the class does not have the .java extension. I'm hoping its not the case in real with the file.

Comment: yeay, it's with .java :)

Comment: if possible can you attach a screenshot of Android Studio IDE displaying project structure?

Answer (score 0):

The xml file name is same for both activities: `activity_main.xml`

You must keep different name because during resource merging, xml is getting replaced. Resource merging merges both product flavor and main source sets.

Comment: Source sets need not to be defined in build.gradle. try cleaning the project. How many flavors do you have?